# Run PHP query through function

Tags: php

I have this php function

```
function showfeed($query_){
    $query = $con->query($query_);
          while ($row=$query->fetch_row()) {
         ...
  }
```

And this is how i run this function

```
showfeed("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE uploads.username = '$NameId' OR uploads.username IN(
        SELECT username FROM followers  WHERE uploads.username = followers.following)ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 0,100");
```

But when i try to run that function i get this error

```
Call to a member function query() on null
```

Comment: Where do you define `$con`?  (According to the error, it's null.  So you're not creating it correctly.)

Comment: So i should put global to `$con`? @David

Comment: No, no you shouldn't.  Sprinkling the `global` keyword haphazardly any time there's an error is going to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: @David then i should pass it?

Comment: There isn't enough context in the code here to know for certain.  Maybe it should be supplied to the function?  Maybe it should be a class-level member?  Maybe it should be created and destroyed entirely within the scope of that function?  There are multiple options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$con` is not defined in the `showFeed` function's scope.

You should pass `$con` as an argument to the function

```
function showFeed($con, $query) {
  $query = $con->query($query);
  ...
}
```

Or use a global variable

```
function showFeed($query)
  global $con;
  $query = $con->query($query);
  ...
}
```

> **Warning:** depending on global variables a lot will make your program really, really bad. You should try to avoid globals as much as possible.

However, in the case of singletons (such as your database connection `$con`), it is common to use globals. A common workaround is to use a singleton class that might look like this

```
class Db {
  static private $con;
  static connection() {
    // if no connection exists
    if (!self::$con)
      // store a reference to a new connection here
      // mysqli_connect is an example here; your code might differ for creating $con
      self::$con = mysqli_connect(...);
    // return the connection reference
    return self::$con;
  }
}
```

Now, because PHP will always allow you to reference the `Db` class in any function (in the same [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)), you don't have to use the global variables anymore

```
function showFeed($query) {
  $query = Db::connection()->query($query);
}
```

In which case it might make sense to make `query` a static method for your `Db` class too!

```
class Db {
  static private $con;
  static public connection() {
    if (!self::$con)
      self::$con = mysqli_connect(...);
    return self::$con;
  }
  static public query($query) {
    // we can get the connection from ourself!
    return self::connection()->query($query)
  }
}
```

Now your function can be simplified

```
function showFeed($query) {
  $query = Db::query($query);
}
```

Of course, you don't want to go overboard with this. I don't know what `$con` is in your particular example – whatever library/adapter you're using might have some of these things built in. These are just here as examples that help you think about the problem differently.

Comment: Thanks,that was a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is because $con doesn't have scope in your function, you would need to either pass it in or make its scope visible through your class I.e `$this->conn`.